# Why do we care about optimal generating matrices?

Tags: coding-theory

So in my coding theory course, it is said that a generating matrix $G$ for a linear code $C$ is optimal if the separation vector $s(G)$ is ordered in such a way that if $G'$ is another generating matrix for $C$, then $s(G)_i\geq s(G')_i$ for all $i$, $1\leq i\leq k$ where $k=\dim C$. As a reminder, $s(G)=(s(G)_1,\dots, s(G)_k)$ where $s(G)_i=\min\{\text{wt}(aG)|\,a_i=1\}$.

Sadly, no explanation is given as to why we actually do care about these optimal matrices. Could anyone explain?

Comment: What is *the separation vector of a generator matrix*? I may have seen it by a different name, but am not sure.

Comment: It's defined by the following relation: $s(G)_i$ is  $\min\{aG\mid a_i = 1\}$ . In other words, you fix the $i$-th coordinate to be 1 in the words you apply $G$ to. Then your vector is $s(G) = (s(G)_1,\dots, s(G)_k)$.

Comment: The products $aG$ are codewords. That is, vectors. How do you define the minimum of a bunch of vectors? Hamming weights?

Comment: Anyway, it's hard to say why this is a useful concept. There exist (possibly vaguely related) metrics like *the generalized Hamming weights* of a linear code. And *widths of the rows of $G$* (= the distance between the 1st and the last one on a given row). These say something about the complexity of the resulting trellis representation of the code. But it looks like this is something I'm unfamiliar with :-(

Comment: Sorry yes, let me edit my comment. You look at the minimum weights. Anyway the idea is that if $s(G)\geq d(C)$, then this bit is more strongly protected against errors, which is useful when you have sensitive bits. My question is really why we care about optimal generating matrices. Anyway, thanks for your input!

Comment: Ok. I guess the idea is, indeed, to protect some input bits more strongly than some others. There are other ways of achieving that, but this seems different from those that I know of. My first guess was that in some iterative decoding scheme these bits could be used in some systematic way, but I'm not sure about that. Sorry.